# Improve my game asset model to match the reference video (Stargate Portal)

Tags: modeling, animation, displacement, shape-keys

I'm working on project which requires an animation whoosh type effect as shown in this video im using as a reference - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dkufTQZnRgk

My project file is in my GitHub here - https://github.com/shaunzorr/whoosh

I have the basic shape animated with a shape key and have added some displacement for the watery effect along with animating this using an empty in object co-ordinates.

I'm struggling on how I can make this look better, specifically the rebounding of the flat surface when the whoosh comes back in and the whoosh as it comes out of the flat surface.

This will be for a game I'm making in Godot so I think am somewhat limited by this, shape keys can be animated in Godot which is helpful.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a try:

[image]

I've used an empty as *Coordinates* object, and moved the empty so that it moves the displace effect:

[image]

Also you could add micro details with a *Bump* node:

[image]